# Facebook comment box height is very small

Tags: facebook

Facebook comment box height was not normal like before..

Is anybody experiencing this problem?

Comment: same problem here  http://www.radicalislam.org/analysis/army-sacks-lt-colonel-course-radical-islam

Answer (score 3):

I think it is facebook's problem.

Facebook comment box of all blogs which uses facebook app was smaller since this afternoon.

edit: I reported this bug to facebook. 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/296608307121527

Comment: subscribe to this issue so it can get quickly fixed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/296608307121527

Answer (score 1):

Im having the same problem, its on facebook end im sure... im going to post a ticket for them to check it out

EDIT:

Here is an issue about it, subscribe to it and comment so it gets fixed soon

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/296608307121527